# Brunch config file conventions.assets: How to copy from non-default locations?

Tags: brunch

According to the brunch documentation the property "conventions.assets" in the config file should be a regexp, but I'm trying to include the following:

```
conventions: {
    assets: /^app\/.*\.html/
}
```

in order to add all the htmls into the public folder. (I know I can create an assets folder and include all the things there, but it's not possible by the moment according the structure we've agreed).

I think this property expect a directory, in this case could I fix this value in order to reach my goal?, with a function maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I could do that overriding the method what the property "assets" accepts.

```
assets: function(path) {
    /**
     * Loops every path and returns path|true|false according what we need
     * @param   path    file or directory's path
     * @returns path    if it is a directory
     *          true    if it fit with the regular expression
     *          false   otherwise
     *
     */
    if( /\/$/.test(path) ) return path;
    return /^app\/.*\.html/.test(path); // RegExp for anything we need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd comment on how my function looks like if someone have a hard time figuring out how to proceed:

```
assets: function(path) {
 /**
  * Loops every path and returns path|true|false according what we need
  * @param   path    file or directory's path
  * @returns path    if it is a directory
  *          true    if it fit with the regular expression
  *          false   otherwise
  *
  */
  if( /\/$/.test(path) ) return path;
  return /^(app|assets)\/.*\.(html|png|jpg|jpeg|eot|svg|ttf|woff)/.test(path);
}
```

This will move files, in both the `app`- and `assets`-folder, with the extensions: `html, png, jpg, jpeg, eot, svg, ttf, woff` to the `public`-folder.

I've decided to move our `assets`-folder to the root-structure, so our structure looks like this now:

```
frontend
  - app
  -- common/
  -- styles/
  -- etc etc
  - assets
  -- index.html
  -- css/
  -- images/
  -- etc etc
```

Comment: Did you also have to add `frontend/assets` to `paths.watched`?  Any other changes to the config to get your asset structure working?  Thanks!

Comment: @cxw Yup! However, we aren't using the assets-override today for some reason. Our `paths.watched` includes `"app"` and `"assets"`